# WebSocket connection. Android

Tags: android, websocket, power-management

How long is possible to keep connection by websocket ?
I mean is if I got the app working in background how will look the consequences 
for internet download and battery life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Socket will be closed when close all your streams or server shuts down your connection,other wise its turns off when your app turns off.